# Mingw32-make Error 1 & 2 while compiling a Libary

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, qmake, mingw32

I tried everything I could think of already to fix it but after several Hours I just give up. I want to compile a Lib with qmake to include a parse for csv files. Sadly when I use mingw32-make I get this Error:

```
C:\Users\Deto24\Downloads\qtcsv-1.5\build>qmake ..\qtcsv.pro CONFIG+=[release] DESTDIR=%cd%
Info: creating stash file C:\Users\Deto24\Downloads\qtcsv-1.5\build\.qmake.stash
Project MESSAGE: === Configuration of qtcsv ===
Project MESSAGE: Qt version: 6.0.2
Project MESSAGE: Library version: 1.5.0
Project MESSAGE: Library files will be created in folder: C:/Users/Deto24/Downloads/qtcsv-1.5/build
Project MESSAGE: === Configuration of qtcsv ===
Project MESSAGE: Qt version: 6.0.2
Project MESSAGE: Library version: 1.5.0
Project MESSAGE: Library files will be created in folder: C:/Users/Deto24/Downloads/qtcsv-1.5/build
Project MESSAGE: === Configuration of qtcsv ===
Project MESSAGE: Qt version: 6.0.2
Project MESSAGE: Library version: 1.5.0
Project MESSAGE: Library files will be created in folder: C:/Users/Deto24/Downloads/qtcsv-1.5/build

C:\Users\Deto24\Downloads\qtcsv-1.5\build>mingw32-make
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Deto24/Downloads/qtcsv-1.5/build'
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O2 -std=gnu++1z -Wall -Wextra -Wextra -Werror -Wformat=2 -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wswitch-enum -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wdisabled-optimization -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DQTCSV_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../qtcsv-1.5 -I. -I../include -IC:/Qt/6.0.2/mingw81_64/include -IC:/Qt/6.0.2/mingw81_64/include/QtCore -Irelease -IC:/Qt/6.0.2/mingw81_64/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o release\writer.o ..\sources\writer.cpp
In file included from ..\sources\writer.cpp:1:
../../qtcsv-1.5/include/qtcsv/writer.h:6:10: fatal error: QTextCodec: No such file or directory
 #include <QTextCodec>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Release:248: release/writer.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Deto24/Downloads/qtcsv-1.5/build'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:45: release] Error 2
```

I'm fairly new to adding Lib's to QT and while there seems no real explains for how to compile those lib's step by step I could gather some Informations by myself. I created the PATH as you can see on the Picture, so I hope that is alright.

[image: PATH]

Any Ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: For Qt6 it `QTextCodec` requires `QT += core5compat`. I expect the code you are building expects Qt5.

Comment: @drescherjm My Question might have been misunderstood, sorry if so. But this is to include the Libary in my QT and after I download it from Github, do I need to compile it first with `Mingw32-make` but there is where I get this Error from. This all happens in **CMD**, so not sure how `QT+= core5compat` helps?

Comment: I believe you either need to switch to use a version of Qt5 instead of Qt6 or you need to modify the pro file for the library your are building add `QT+= core5compat`. The first option may be the best because there may be other Qt6 incompatibilities since the library you are compiling does not appear to support Qt6 without modification.

Comment: Here is the link from the Qt6 documentation that specifies the need for `QT += core5compat`: [https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtextcodec.html](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtextcodec.html)